# Sklearn: GridSearchCV over n_iter parameter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

Sklearn [recommends](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#rolling-your-own-estimator) that for iterative estimators the number of iterations should be specified by the `n_iter` parameter of `.fit()`.

Running a grid search for optimal hyperparameters with [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) allows you to specify only ranges of values for parameters that can be set with `estimator.set_params()`.

So I am wondering, how do I run a grid search for (amongst others) the number of iterations?
A solution would be to change the estimator code, so that `n_iter` is set in the constructor and by `.set_params()`, but for some reason this is explicitely not recommended, as explained above.

**Edit:**
Here is an example:

Create an estimator that requires two parameters:

```
estimator = SomeEstimator(alpha=5, theta=0.001)
```

You can fit an estimator on data X and labels y with the `fit()` method. In addition, assume that the estimator runs an iterative algorithm and you can specify how many times it is supposed to run. Sklearn recommends to use the parameter `n_iter` of the `fit()` function for this:

```
estimator.fit(X, y, n_iter=4)
```

To find the optimal parameter values for alpha and theta you can run a GridSearchCV, which runs `estimator.fit()` for all combinations of those parameters:

```
GridSearchCV(estimator, {'alpha':[5, 6], 'theta':[0.1, 0.01, 0.001]}).fit(X, y, n_iter=4)
```

This will run the estimator for the combinations of alpha/theta:

```
(5, 0.1)
(5, 0.01)
(5, 0.001)
(6, 0.1)
(6, 0.01)
(6, 0.001)
```

But I want to these six combinations for different values of `n_iter` (1..10). Of course I can use a for-loop, but thats not the point of GridSearchCV.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more preferably with an example?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Ok, but is `n_iter` a hyperparameter?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GridSearchCV` to find the best `n_iter` hyper parameter with an estimator that has that as a parameter, in the same way as other hyper parameters. The below works find on sklearn 0.19.0

```
np.random.seed(42)
clf = SGDClassifier()
params = {'n_iter': [30, 50, 100], 'alpha': [0.01, 0.1, 1.0]}
gs = GridSearchCV(clf, params, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)
X = np.random.random((100, 5))
y = np.random.choice([0, 1], 100)
gs.fit(X, y)
print gs.best_params_
```

**Output:**

```
{'alpha': 0.1, 'n_iter': 30}
```

Comment: That is deprecated in current version and will be removed. Thats why I asked the question if its considered a valid hyper-parameter or not. Which in my opinion it should not be.

Comment: Can you point me to where this is the docs? I can see that `fit_params` is deprecated but can't see anything that suggests this won't work. Also I don't seem to get a future warning (other than the one thrown for the SGDClassifier)

Comment: I am not saying it wont work as you describe. It will. But this parameter is deprecated for SGDClassifier in 0.19. Look [below the `n_iter` here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) But what my point is, `n_iter` in general should not be considered a hyperparameter because most of the times, a greater `n_iter` will always be selected by the tuning. And it depends on the `threshold` of the loss to be crossed. So we can indirectly have other parameters which represent this better.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I agree that this is the case most of the time.

Comment: In many cases estimator performance stagnates (or almost) at a certain value of `n_iter`. In that case it would be interesting to find that value. In that case, only looking at the best parameter selected by gridsearch does indeed not make much sense. But you can use gridsearch to for example plot the sampled hyperparamter surface, and then it makes perfectly sense to include `n_iter`.